# How to correctly call this method?

Tags: java, foreach

For my assignment, I have been asked to complete the following:

**1.** Create a second method called eat in the Animal class. This method should take a Food object and an Integer as parameters.

**2.** Use an appropriate loop in the new eat method to feed the Food object to the Animal, the number of times specified in the Integer parameter.

I have created the while lop that I think is correct but I'm having problems calling it, this is what the for loop looks like:

```
public void eat(Food food, int count) {
    while (count > 0) {
        addFood(food);
        count--;
    }
}
```

This is declared in a class called Wolf which extends a method called Carnivore which is extended from an abstract Animal method. Given the specification, how would I print this while loop out in my main method and make it output something along the lines of `Wolf has eaten " + //value of loop iteration + " times`? Any help on how to correctly call this method is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `method called Wolf which extends` You mean class not method

Comment: I did mean class, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following steps in your `main`():

(1) Create an object for `Food` called `food`

(2) Create an object for `Wolf` called `wolf`

(3) invoke `wolf.eat(food, count);` //pass the food object and count & print the result inside

Comment: Update your question with the latest code

Answer (score 0):

```
public void main()
{
    Food food = new Food();
    Animal wolf = new Wolf();
    int count = 10;
    wolf.eat(food,count);
    System.out.println("Wolf has eaten" + count + "times");
}
```

//make reference of base class to access the eat method from base class..